# PowerShell 5.0: How can I call a method of an object in a remote session?

Tags: class, powershell, session, static-methods

my problem is that I put all the important data and methods into an object which I passed as param to a remote session, but the methods are in the session not available. This is because they have to be static, right? But an object instance can't call a static method and I don't want to pass the methods additionally to the session. Is there an alternative so that I can do this in a neat way? (I work with PowerShell 5.0 and want to use classes)

Example (Neither static nor non static methods are passed to the remote session):

```
function main()
{
$CredPath   = "C:\temp\cred.txt"
$Cred = getCredentials -CredPath $CredPath
Class Serv
{
    [String]$Cn 
    [String]$Services1
    static [String]$Services2 = "SysMain"
    [String]$Eventlog 
    [String]$OccurredErrors 
    [String]$Inf1
    [String]$Inf2 

    Serv([String]$Cn)
    {
        $this.Cn = $Cn
        $this.Services1 = "SysMain"
    }

     Serv()
    {
        $this.Cn = "ignipes.hsch.lab"
        $this.Services1 = "SysMain"

    }

    [void] setInf1()
    {
        $this.Inf1 = get-service $this.Services1
    }

    static [String] setInf2()
    {
        return (get-service ([Serv]::Services2))

    }
}

$Serv = [Serv]::new("ignipes.hsch.lab")
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Serv.Cn -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction Stop 

$ServResult = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
                     param ($Serv)

                     $Serv.setInf1()
                     $Serv.Inf2 = [Serv]::setInf2()

                     $Serv

                    } -ArgumentList $Serv

       Remove-PSSession -ComputerName "ignipes.hsch.lab"
$Serv.Inf1 = $ServResult.Inf1
$Serv.Inf2 = $ServResult.Inf2
$Serv

}
main
```

Comment: Bit difficult to recommend a solution on the information you've provided. What do the methods do? Do they need access to anything, locally or remote? Do they affect anything locally or remote?

Comment: The object contains variables, which provide information about the things that should be checked remote and contain the results of the checks. The methods should do the checks on the remote system. For example get-eventlog, get-service...

Comment: @Temerita Could you post an example of what you're struggling with? ie. a class definition and a call/invocation that doesn't work remotely?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've added an example